# 802.1x Authenticator & Authentication server on same machine

Tags: networking, linux

I want to be able to restrict the devices that can connect to the Ethernet port of a Linux PC (so that only a single laptop can be used with it). The linux PC is not connected to any other networking infrastructure

Is it possible to have both the authenticator (hostapd?) and an authentication server (freeRADIUS?) on the same Linux machine, so that I can use 802.1x to limit the hosts which can communicate with the ethernet port? Would having both on the same machine reduce the security level (would it be in effect, putting the auth server in the DMZ?)

Is this possible, or is there another technology that is more appropriate?

I ideally want to authenticate to the laptop, rather than a specific user - it is shared between multiple users in the organisation. I'd been hoping we could authenticate with a key/certificate, so that any laptop with this key can communicate (rather than having to maintain a manual list of all MACs).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do exactly what you’ve outlined.

In fact, 802.1X doesn’t even require a separate authentication server at all; that’s just an implementation detail. But since most implementers have chosen to have a separate authentication server that is reached via RADIUS, a lot of people have come away with the mistaken impression that 802.1X requires RADIUS.